# Map displaying a grey area - android

Tags: android, maps

What is possibly wrong with this code? 
I'm not seeing what could possibly be intrefering and the API key is right but it continues to show a grey area.

Can someone give a touch on this?

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
package com.example;

*ALL THE IMPORTS


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private int mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        MapFragment mapFragment =  (MapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(mapType);
    }
}
```

ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="11" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>


    <!--Required permissions-->

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <!--Used by the API to download map tiles from Google Maps servers: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!--Allows the API to access Google web-based services: -->
    <uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <!--Allows the API to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <!--Optional permissions-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!--Version 2 of the Google Maps Android API requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="my api"/>
        </application>

</manifest>
```

Seriously, this maps thing is driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

Check these things

1. Correct API Key and

   2. in manifest
2. Google maps should be on in your devloper console
3. INTERNET PERMISSION in manifest
4. Updated google play services

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found a solution, pretty stupid in my opinion but it worked.

I had to declare the api key in the layout.xml

After that, everything worked like charm